# Why does nullable = false force a FK to be put in on insert, but without it it does an update to set the FK in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Using JPA annotations and hibernate we ran in to an issue recently with a unidirectional onetomany mapping that looked like this:

```
@Entity
public class FooOrder extends AbstractEntity{

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fooOrderId")
    private List<FooItem> fooItems = new ArrayList<FooItem>();
    public void addFooItem(foo item properties here)
    {
       fooItems.add(fooItem);
    }
}


@Entity
public class FooItem extends AbstractEntity {

   SomeRandomStuffButNoLinkToParent
}
```

The test code was basically this:

```
FooOrder fooOrder = new FooOrder(stuff here);

fooOrder.addFooItem(foo item properties here);

fooOrder = fooOrderRepository.save(fooOrder);
```

When we run tests on this we get sql that looks something like this:

```
insert FooOrder(columns here)
insert FooItem(columns here missing the FK to FooOrder)
update FooItem set FooOrderFK to proper key.
```

but if I set `@JoinColumn(name = "activeOrderId", nullable = false)` then my sql looks something like this:

```
insert FooOrder(columns here)
insert FooItem(columns here with FK to FooOrder)
```

Why does hibernate set the FK through an update if it's nullable, but set it in the insert when it's not nullable?

Comment: why is it an issue? It seems like an implementation/design decision in hibernate

Comment: I happened to run across this because a field in the database was set to non-nullable, even though the mapping didn't reflect this. It was good thing to run across since it let us know that we had a mismatch, but I thought it was interesting, and it seemed odd to do 2 operations when one would suffice.

Comment: if the fk-column is not nullable, the persist operation on the entity must fail atomically; if it is not, the insert operation on the relation could fail by itself, and recovering (committing the main entity or rolling back everything) would be left to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well when the foreign key is not null able

```
insert FooOrder(columns here)
insert FooItem(columns here with FK to FooOrder)
```

Is the only way to actually execute the inserts. So the real question is why this is not always done this way.

My take on this is that the way using updates works in times when the other would not ever work.

Let assume we have some kind of circular foreingn key relationship.
A has a foreign key to B
B has a foreign key to A
if none of this foreign keys is nullable there might be no way to insert this.
You can not insert A first because the foreign key to B can not be null.
Same goes for B.

Also note that my example might be over simplyfied. This circular foreign key can be caused by any number of tables.

So first inserting the data and then adding the foreign keys is just the way that works in this more complicated scenario. Your not null constraint forces Hibernate to take another way. For the default case first inserting then adding the keys is just he better idear.